# Error in nextTick: "TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I know this question has been asked so many times but still I am not getting whats wrong as many things are right from those answers.

I am trying to use select jquery plugin inside vue js. 
Here is my code

```
mounted(){
      Vue.nextTick(function () {
        $('.s').select2()
       //$('.form-control').css('background-color', 'red'); // This codes works perfectly
     })

 }
```

In this case I get this error `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"`

It might be order of script. Here is how I am ordering my script in `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/adminapp.js', 'public/js/adminapp.js').version(); // This is all about vue js

mix.scripts([
'public/admin/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
'public/admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
'public/admin/dist/js/adminlte.min.js',
'public/admin/bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js', // select jquery plugin

 ], 'public/admin/js/all.js').version();
```

In my blade file I tried to test by swapping `all.js` and `adminapp.js` and same results.

Another interesting thing is that, if I declare select2 inside blade file and not in vue like this it WORKS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Initialize Select2 Elements
   $('.s').select2()
});
```

However, if I use like this, when browsing through router in vue I get no effect of this plugin. Only on first load.

Any idea and help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have never used VueJS, but I believe it's like Angular or React. So that's what's wrong : using a jQuery plugin inside a Vue (or Angular, or React) based application. Don't mix these guys, ever.

Comment: Haha, I understand. It always same case. Thanks for the suggestions :)